# what is the best way to handle reserved key words of PostgreSQL when using Mybatis

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mybatis, quoted-identifier

when I created a column like `name` or `password` and so on in PostgreSQL 13. The PostgreSQL may seem it as a reserved key word. so the MyBatis SQL would like this:

```
INSERT INTO apple_server_notification_record (created_time, updated_time, notification_type, auto_renew_product_id, auto_renew_status, auto_renew_status_change_date, auto_renew_status_change_date_ms, auto_renew_status_change_date_pst, environment, `password`, bid, bvrs) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

it will add `` automaticlly in the SQL. But when execute the sql in PostgreSQL 13. show this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
  Position: 249
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis/mapper/dolphin/AppleServerNotificationRecordMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.dolphin.soa.post.dao.AppleServerNotificationRecordMapper.insertSelective-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO apple_server_notification_record (created_time, updated_time, notification_type, auto_renew_product_id, auto_renew_status, auto_renew_status_change_date, auto_renew_status_change_date_ms, auto_renew_status_change_date_pst, environment, `password`, bid, bvrs) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
  Position: 249
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
  Position: 249
```

I could solved it by change the columns `password` to `apple_auth_password`, I known it will fix the problem. But In my code, I must tranform the mapping explicit in receive request from apple. My entity define like this:

```
private String password;
```

any good suggestion to solve the problem? what would you do when encount this problem?

Comment: You are showing back-ticks here. Are those really single-quote marks that you are seeing?

Comment: Back ticks are of no use for quoting identifiers in Postgres. They're native to MySQL and MariaDB. For Postgres (and standard SQL) double quotes must be used to quote identifiers.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

you could change the auto generator config code config of Mybatis-generator:

```
  <property name="autoDelimitKeywords" value="true"/>
    <!--
    the beginningDelimiter and endingDelimiter using " by default
    when using PostgreSQL using "
    when using MySQL, we should change to `
     -->
    <property name="beginningDelimiter" value="&quot;"/>
    <property name="endingDelimiter" value="&quot;"/>
```